# Where is angular-cli package.json?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular2error problem now. I get a message

> Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined

I saw the information ([Angular 2 - Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282288/angular-2-cannot-read-property-asseturl-of-undefined)).

I want to edit `package.json`. But, I can not find this file.

I am using nodebrew to install node.js.

```
ng new app
```

This command results in this error:

> Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined

The package file has not been created yet.

Comment: Try uninstalling and clearing your npm cache and installing angular cli again

Comment: 1stCommand[npm uninstall -g angular-cli]     2ndCommand[npm cache clean]  3rdCommand[npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17]   4th[ng -v] 　displey char [Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined]   Do you know other procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed angular cli with old command `npm install -g angular-cli` and its incompatible with current version of node or npm.

Try to uninstall old version and install a new one like:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Don't forget @ sign, without it cli start to have weird behavior.

Comment: The latest version has (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053160/uncaught-referenceerror-ng-jsonp-req0-finished-is-not-defined-at) error.  I would like to use angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.17.

Comment: Then use `npm install -g @angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17`, because of newer version of node

Comment: pakeageversion is [node -v 6.8.0]  [ npm -v 3.10.8]

Comment: Try to update node and npm, maybe you have versions incompatibility

Comment: angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.17  node 6.8.0  npm 3.10.8    I confirmed that these three are compatible.

Comment: An error occurred.　$ npm install -g @angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/kuniatus/node_modules/@angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14268 , all your problems because of node version, please update it.